# View the instantiated C++ types in Visual Studio without variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, types

When debugging in Visual Studio, is it possible to see the instantiated types of the template parameters? I can edit the code and often declare a variable of such a type; though not always, and it is a hassle. Similarly for `typedef` or `using` declarations, I'd often like to view their instantiated types.

```
template <typename T>
int foo()
{
    using type = T;
    return 42;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo<double>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about here. View them *where*?

Comment: If I knew that I'd tell you :) For variables, I can view their values *and their types* in a range of debug windows such as "Autos", "Locals" and Watch1".

Comment: Can't you hover over the type name and see the type in a tooltip?

Comment: Indeed, you would think so, but no, it doesn't happen.

Comment: Which version of VS are we talking here? Can you make a brand new project to check only templated parameters when debugging? Because normally It should work as expected.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015, but I've just tried with VS 2013 too. Tooltips appear above variables, but not templates, or type aliases.

Comment: Templates produce *code*, not bugs.  Don't use a debugger, look at the linker's MAP file for example.